# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cot(\pi n\sqrt{61})}{n^3}=-\frac{16793\pi^3}{45660\sqrt{61}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory, continued-fractions, diophantine-approximation

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cot(\pi n\sqrt{61})}{n^3}=-\frac{16793\pi^3}{45660\sqrt{61}}.$$
>
> - Prove it converges and,
> - evaluate the series.

---

For the first part of the question, I prove it converges by considering the irrationality measure,

$$|\sin (n\pi\sqrt{61})|=|\sin (n\pi\sqrt{61}-m\pi)|\ge \frac{2}{\pi}|n\pi\sqrt{61}-m\pi|\ge 2n\left|\sqrt{61}-\frac{m}{n}\right|>\frac{C}{n},$$

so
$$\left|\frac{\cot(\pi n\sqrt{61})}{n^3}\right|\le\left|\frac{1}{n^3\sin(\pi n\sqrt{61})}\right|<\frac{C}{n^2}.$$

How to evaluate the series?

I have found a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1658250/394456).

I apologize for incorrect information in the previous post.

Comment: Maybe residue theorem?

Comment: It is hard to use residue theorem directly since cotangent is a meromorphic function.

Comment: If it is $\sqrt{63}$ instead of $\sqrt{61}$, the problem would be much easier.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In general
$$F(\alpha) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot(n\pi \alpha)}{n^3}$$
converges and can be explicitly calculated when $\alpha$ is a **quadratic irrational**. The convergence in this case is easily seen as $\alpha$ has irrationality measure $2$. More precisely, $F(\alpha)/\pi^3 \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ when $\alpha$ is quadratic irrational.

The procedure below also works when $n^3$ is replaced by any $n^{2k+1}$.

---

Let $$g(z) = \frac{\cot(z\pi \alpha)\cot(z\pi)}{z^3}$$ then $g$ has simple poles at non-zero integer multiples of $1$ and $1/\alpha$, and $5$-th order pole at $0$. Let $R_N$ denote a large rectangle with corners at $N(\pm 1 \pm i)$. Then contour integration gives
$$\tag{1}\sum_{\substack{n\in R_N \\ n\neq 0}} \frac{\cot(n\pi\alpha)}{\pi n^3} + \sum_{\substack{n/\alpha\in R_N \\ n\neq 0}} \frac{\alpha^2\cot(n\pi/\alpha)}{\pi n^3}-\frac{\pi ^2 \left(\alpha^4-5 \alpha^2+1\right)}{45 \alpha} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{R_N} g(z)dz$$
I claim there exists a sequence of integers $N_1, N_2, \cdots$ such that RHS tends to $0$. Note that $\cot(z\pi)$ is uniformly bounded on the annulus $R_{N+3/4} - R_{N+1/4}$ when $N$ is an integer. Hence by equidistribution of $n\alpha$ modulo $1$, we can find integers $N_i$ such that both $\cot(z\pi\alpha)$ and $\cot(z\pi)$ are uniformly bounded on $R_{N_i+3/4} - R_{N_i+1/4}$.

**Since we already know the series converges**, from $(1)$:
$$\tag{2}F(\alpha) + \alpha^2F(\frac{1}{\alpha}) = \underbrace{\frac{\pi ^3 \left(\alpha^4-5 \alpha^2+1\right)}{90 \alpha}}_{\rho(\alpha)}$$
Note that obviously $F(\alpha+1)=F(\alpha)$.

---

Let the continued fraction expansion of $\alpha$ be given by
$$\alpha = [a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots]$$
Successive complete quotients are denoted by:
$$\zeta_0 = [a_0;a_1,a_2,\cdots]\qquad \zeta_1 = [a_1;a_2,a_3,\cdots]\qquad \zeta_2 = [a_2;a_3,a_4,\cdots]$$
Then $(2)$ and periodicity implies for $k\geq 0$:
$$\tag{3} F(\zeta_{k+1}) + \zeta_{k+1}^2 F(\zeta_k) = \rho(\zeta_{k+1})$$
If continued fraction of $\alpha$ is of form
$$\alpha = [a_0;a_1,\cdots,a_m,\overline{b_1,\cdots,b_r}]$$
Then $\zeta_{m+r+1} = \zeta_{m+1}$, so we eventually entered a cycle. $(3)$ gives a system of $m+r+1$ linear equations (by setting $k=0,\cdots,m+r$), with $m+r+1$ variables: $F(\zeta_0), F(\zeta_1),\cdots,F(\zeta_{m+r})$.
$$\begin{cases}
F(\zeta_1) + \zeta_1^2 F(\zeta_0) &= \rho(\zeta_1) \\ 
F(\zeta_2) + \zeta_2^2 F(\zeta_1) &= \rho(\zeta_2) \\ 
\cdots \\
F(\zeta_{m+1}) + \zeta_{m+1}^2 F(\zeta_{m+r}) &= \rho(\zeta_{m+1})
\end{cases}$$
Solving it gives the value of $F(\zeta_0)=F(\alpha)$.

---

For $\alpha = \sqrt{61} = [7;\overline{1,4,3,1,2,2,1,3,4,1,14}]$, we have
$$\begin{aligned} \zeta_0 = \sqrt{61} \qquad \zeta_1 &= \frac{1}{12}(7+\sqrt{61}) \\
\zeta_2 = \frac{1}{3}(5+\sqrt{61}) \qquad \zeta_3 &= \frac{1}{4}(7+\sqrt{61})\\
\zeta_4 = \frac{1}{9}(5+\sqrt{61}) \qquad \zeta_5 &= \frac{1}{5}(4+\sqrt{61})\\
\zeta_6 = \frac{1}{5}(6+\sqrt{61}) \qquad \zeta_7 &= \frac{1}{9}(4+\sqrt{61})\\
\zeta_8 = \frac{1}{4}(5+\sqrt{61}) \qquad \zeta_9 &= \frac{1}{3}(7+\sqrt{61}) \\
\zeta_{10} = \frac{1}{12}(5+\sqrt{61}) \qquad \zeta_{11} &= \frac{1}{12}(7+\sqrt{61}) \end{aligned}$$ solving the above system gives the result.

---

A few examples: for $\alpha = (1+\sqrt{5})/2$, the continued fraction has period $1$, direct substitution into $(2)$ gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot(n\pi \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})}{n^3} = -\frac{\pi ^3}{45 \sqrt{5}}$$
Complexity of result increases as period of $\alpha$ increases. For $\alpha = \sqrt{211}$, which has period $26$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot(n\pi \sqrt{211})}{n^3} = \frac{128833758679 \pi ^3}{383254107060 \sqrt{211}}$$
For $\alpha = \sqrt{1051}$, with period $50$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot(n\pi \sqrt{1051})}{n^3} = \frac{47332791433774124737806821 \pi ^3}{589394448213331173141730140 \sqrt{1051}}$$
When $\alpha$ is not a "pure" quadratic irrational, the result involves "constant term" (because of non-trivial automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$):
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot(n\pi(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt{7}}{3}))}{n^3} = 
\frac{13 \pi ^3}{288}+\frac{104771 \pi ^3}{1244160 \sqrt{7}}$$
The closed-form [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658250/compute-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n3-sinn-pi-sqrt2) follows immediately by noting $\csc x = \cot (x/2) - \cot x$.

---

I wrote a Mathematica code to evaluate this sum. The command `cotsum[Sqrt[61]]` evaluates the sum in the question. You can try other quadratic irrationals as well.

This algorithm can be made more efficient, but I don't have much motivation to optimize it.

```
cotsum[x_] /; QuadraticIrrationalQ[x] := 
 Module[{a1 = x, list, l, r, i, nlist, solution, output, equation, 
   string}, list = ContinuedFraction[a1];
  l = Length[list] - 1;
  r = Length[list[[l + 1]]]; Global`f[a_] := (1 - 5 a^2 + a^4)/90/a;
  i = 1; string = "{";
  While[i < l + r + 1, string = string <> "x" <> ToString[i] <> ",";
   i++]; string = StringTake[string, StringLength[string] - 1] <> "}";
  Do[Evaluate[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i + 1]]] = 
    FromContinuedFraction[Drop[list, i]], {i, 1, l - 1}];
  nlist = list[[l + 1]];
  Do[Evaluate[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i + l + 1]]] = 
    FromContinuedFraction[{Flatten[
       Append[Drop[nlist, i], Take[nlist, i]]]}], {i, 0, r - 1}];
  equation = 
   Table[ToExpression[
     "x" <> ToString[i + 1] <> "+a" <> ToString[i + 1] <> "^2*x" <> 
      ToString[i] <> "==f[a" <> ToString[i + 1] <> "]"], {i, 1, 
     r + l - 1}];
  equation = 
   Append[equation, 
    ToExpression[
     "x" <> ToString[l + 1] <> "+a" <> ToString[l + 1] <> "^2*x" <> 
      ToString[r + l] <> "==f[a" <> ToString[l + 1] <> "]"]];
  solution = Solve[equation, ToExpression[string]]; Clear["a*"];
  output = (ToExpression[string][[1]] /. Flatten[solution])*Pi^3; 
  Clear[f];
  FullSimplify[output]]
```

Comment: This is amazing.

Comment: (+1) Very good explanation.

Comment: Truly perfect and awesome.. Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems your notation with the $\zeta_j$ gives exactly the middle column in Prof. Lubin's classroom method for solving Pell's equation. I posted that as an answer, I have it written as a program that produces the Latex code in full, ready for pasting in an answer box on this site. I suspect Prof. Lubin's method is very similar to what Fermat, Wallis, and Brouncker would have used, being entirely made up of integer operations.

Comment: (+1) Well done.

Comment: +1 and it appears Ramanujan also said the same thing. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/907480/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Yes, this is the case when $\alpha$ is purely imaginary in $(2)$. I think the sum $\sum \coth(\pi n)/n^3$ is also due to Ramanujan.

Comment: I think there is a general formula for such sums which Ramanujan proved. Here is one particular example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/991066/72031

Answer (score 9):

Sigh. I believe that Pisco's sequence from $\zeta_1$ to $\zeta_{11}$ matches the middle column (all plus signs) in Prof. Lubin's no-calculator method for solving Pell, and is likely what Fermat, Wallis, Brouncker used all those years ago. Yes! If I continued one more step, I would get $\zeta_{11},$ which equals $\zeta_1$

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 61} = 7 +     \frac{  \sqrt {61} - 7 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{12 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{12 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 12 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{3 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{4 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 4 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {61} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 4 }{5 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 6 }{5 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {61} - 6 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 6 }{5 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 4 }{5 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {61} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 4 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{4 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{3 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{12 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{12 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 12 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{1 } = 14 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 7 & & 1 & & 4 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 4 & & 1 & & 14 & & 1 & & 4 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 4 & & 1 & & 14 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 39 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 125 }{ 16 }   & &   \frac{ 164 }{ 21 }   & &   \frac{ 453 }{ 58 }   & &   \frac{ 1070 }{ 137 }   & &   \frac{ 1523 }{ 195 }   & &   \frac{ 5639 }{ 722 }   & &   \frac{ 24079 }{ 3083 }   & &   \frac{ 29718 }{ 3805 }   & &   \frac{ 440131 }{ 56353 }   & &   \frac{ 469849 }{ 60158 }   & &   \frac{ 2319527 }{ 296985 }   & &   \frac{ 7428430 }{ 951113 }   & &   \frac{ 9747957 }{ 1248098 }   & &   \frac{ 26924344 }{ 3447309 }   & &   \frac{ 63596645 }{ 8142716 }   & &   \frac{ 90520989 }{ 11590025 }   & &   \frac{ 335159612 }{ 42912791 }   & &   \frac{ 1431159437 }{ 183241189 }   & &   \frac{ 1766319049 }{ 226153980 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -12 & & 3 & & -4 & & 9 & & -5 & & 5 & & -9 & & 4 & & -3 & & 12 & & -1 & & 12 & & -3 & & 4 & & -9 & & 5 & & -5 & & 9 & & -4 & & 3 & & -12 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 61 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  7  \\  
  \frac{ 7 }{ 1 }   & 7^2 - 61 \cdot 1^2 = -12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & 8^2 - 61 \cdot 1^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 39 }{ 5 }   & 39^2 - 61 \cdot 5^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 125 }{ 16 }   & 125^2 - 61 \cdot 16^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 164 }{ 21 }   & 164^2 - 61 \cdot 21^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 453 }{ 58 }   & 453^2 - 61 \cdot 58^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 1070 }{ 137 }   & 1070^2 - 61 \cdot 137^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1523 }{ 195 }   & 1523^2 - 61 \cdot 195^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 5639 }{ 722 }   & 5639^2 - 61 \cdot 722^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 24079 }{ 3083 }   & 24079^2 - 61 \cdot 3083^2 = 12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 29718 }{ 3805 }   & 29718^2 - 61 \cdot 3805^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
  \frac{ 440131 }{ 56353 }   & 440131^2 - 61 \cdot 56353^2 = 12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 469849 }{ 60158 }   & 469849^2 - 61 \cdot 60158^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 2319527 }{ 296985 }   & 2319527^2 - 61 \cdot 296985^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 7428430 }{ 951113 }   & 7428430^2 - 61 \cdot 951113^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 9747957 }{ 1248098 }   & 9747957^2 - 61 \cdot 1248098^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 26924344 }{ 3447309 }   & 26924344^2 - 61 \cdot 3447309^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 63596645 }{ 8142716 }   & 63596645^2 - 61 \cdot 8142716^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 90520989 }{ 11590025 }   & 90520989^2 - 61 \cdot 11590025^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 335159612 }{ 42912791 }   & 335159612^2 - 61 \cdot 42912791^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 1431159437 }{ 183241189 }   & 1431159437^2 - 61 \cdot 183241189^2 = -12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1766319049 }{ 226153980 }   & 1766319049^2 - 61 \cdot 226153980^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

Comment: Why was this down voted??

Comment: I did not downvote, but maybe the long table broke someone's browser :)

Comment: (+1) to annihilate the down vote